# How Create User ID for GA4 to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

#### Purpose

I want to create `user_id` in **GA4** which was linked to **BigQuery**.

#### What I've tried

I followed this [document](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9213390?hl=en):

1. **GTM** to manage **GA4**.
2. **GA4** links to **BigQuery**.

   (Now I got data from my website, and data can collect in **BigQuery**.)
3. Passed `user_id` to `dataLayer`:

   - I've added the following script in `HEADER` which above `gtm.js`.
   - I'm not sure whether using a string (`USER_ID`) as input at this step will affect the result or not.

   ```
   <script>
      dataLayer.push({
        'user_id': 'USER_ID'
      });
   </script>
   ```
4. Create variable of dataLayer:

   [image]
5. Adjust GTM code:

   [image]

#### Expected & Results

- I expected that I build comparision like:

  [image]

  However, I cannot do that:

  [image]
- I expected my **BigQuery** can get a new column `user_id` (no happen)

#### Questions

- Did I mess up something in the process?
- Could the `user_id` passed from the front-end and back-end be passed to **BigQuery** as I expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your process 5

The key should be `user_id` Not `userId`. It's different for GA4.

Follow the [document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/user-id?client_type=gtm)